# Error: 150 : "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql, sql

> error (#1005 - No puedo crear tabla `mydb`.`recibos` (Error: 150
>   "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"))

Este es el código que utilicé. Sin embargo, el error que me da tiene que ver con un foreign key, aunque en el código no estoy creando ninguna clave ajena:

```
CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS `recibos`(
  id_recibos INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_recibos`)
);
```

Comment: Esa query funciona correctamente, algo más habrá en esa base de datos que te impide crear la tabla.

Comment: pues estaba revisando todo lo que estuve haciendo en esa base de datos y me di cuenta que nunca ejecute un drop sobre la base de datos y me puse a investigar un poco y al parecer solo se desapareció la tabla y permanece el error al tratar de crear una tabla con el mismo nombre. Dejare detalles cuando encuentre el motivo por el que desapareció la tabla.